Pandas set_index on multiple columns not working
I'm working with a DataFrame and trying to set a multi-level index using two existing columns,  and . Here's my code:
import pandas as pd

# ... (Code to read CSV file)

# Create projection DataFrame
projection = df[['<DATE>', '<TIME>', '<HIGH>']]

# Attempt to set multi-level index
projection.set_index(['<DATE>', '<TIME>'])

print(projection)

The problem is, the index remains unchanged after using set_index. I expect the DataFrame to have a multi-level index with  as the first level and  as the second.

The set_index method creates a new DataFrame with the specified columns as the index. To modify the existing projection DataFrame in-place, you need to use the inplace=True argument.
projection.set_index(['<DATE>', '<TIME>'], inplace=True) 

or use the output of it
projection = projection.set_index(['<DATE>', '<TIME>'])

